# ffmpeg: no background sound

Tags: 20.04, sound, ffmpeg

I can see my video but I cannot hear some background sound. This is the command I'm using:

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -video_size 1366x768 -framerate 20 -i :11 /home/userx/Desktop/out.mpg
```

How can I enable sound?

Answer (score 0):

**Pulse only:**

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -video_size 1366x768 -framerate 30 -i :0.0 -f pulse -i default -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 128k -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -crf 18 -pix_fmt yuv420p desktop-out.mkv
```

**Pulse with ALSA:**

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -ac 2 -i pulse -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 128k -f x11grab -r 30 -s 1366x768 -i :0.0 -aspect 16:9 -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -crf 18 -pix_fmt yuv420p desktop-out.mkv
```

**NOTE:**

Use `-f oss -i /dev/dsp1` to capture sound from microphone.

Audio libraries:

mp3: `libmp3lame`  webm: `libvpx`  ogg: `libvorbis`  opus: `libopus`  aac: `libfaac`